# Why is the sine function analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}$ $\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}$ $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$
Let me define the sine function in the geometric way.
I want to say that the sine of an angle is `perpendicular divided by hypotenuse.'
So first let us define what we mean by an angle.

Let $C=\set{(x, y)\in \R^2:\ x^2+y^2=1, 0\leq x, y\leq 1}$ be the part of the unit circle in the first quadrant.
To each point $p$ of $C$ we will associate a numerical quantity $f(p)$ which we will refer to as the angle corresponding to $p$.
This quantity $f(p)$ is the length of the arc along $C$ joining the points $(1, 0)$ and $p$.
Then $\sin(f(p))$ is declared to be equal to $p_2$, the $y$-coordinate of $p_2$.

So we need to recall the notion of length.
Given a twice differentiable curve $\gamma:[a, b]\to \R^2$, we define the **length** of $\gamma$ as
$$
\int_a^b \norm{\gamma'(t)}\ dt
$$
Here the norm is the Euclidean norm.
Intuitively, this says that the distance travelled by the particle whose position is governed by $\gamma$ is the integral of its speed, which makes a lot of sense.
It is important to note that one may re-parametrize $\gamma$ and not alter the length.
More precisely, if $\alpha:[c, d] \to [a, b]$ is a diffeomorphism, then $\gamma\circ \alpha$ has the same length as $\gamma$.

Now let us define the notion of angle using this.
We define a map $\gamma:[0, 1]\to \R^2$ as
$$\gamma(t) = (1-t, \sqrt{1-(1-t)^2})$$
Note that the usual parameterization of the circle comes from trigonometric functions but we cannot use that since those are what we are trying to define here.

We declare that the **angle** associated to a point $p\in C$ as the length of $\gamma:[0, t_0]\to \R^2$ where $t_0\in [0, 1]$ is the unique element such that $\gamma(t_0)=p$.
Let us denote the length of $\gamma:[0, 1]\to \R^2$ as $\pi/2$.

Finally, we define the **sine function** $\sin:[0, \pi/2]\to \R$ by declaring $\sin(a)$ to be the second coordinate of the point in $C$ whose angle is $a$.
We extend this function to all of $\R$ in the obvious way.

It can be showing using geometric arguments that the sine function thus defined is differentiable and its derivative happens to be the cosine function (which we can similarly define as the `base upon hypotenuse' function).
The cosine function itself turns out to be differentiable and its derivate is the negative of the sine function.
Therefore the sine function is smooth.

> **Question.**
> However, it is not clear to me how to show that the sine function, as defined above, is analytic.

Can somebody please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, you want to know why the $\sin$ you defined above has a power series that converges on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Yes that is what I am asking. Basically, I do not feel any motivation if one defines sine by writing $x-x^3/3! + x^5/5!+\cdots$. So I would like to see how the above defintion, which seems meaningful to me, is same as the analytic one.

Comment: @caffeinemachine Well, since you've defined derivatives; in fact since you've concluded that $\sin$ is smooth on all of $\mathrm R,$ can't you just do its Taylor development about $0$?

Comment: @Allawonder There exist nonzero smooth functions on $\mathbb R$ which have all derivatives $0$ at $0$. So it is not clear as to how your suggestion works. Thanks.

Comment: @caffeinemachine In this case as is usually proved in elementary calculus classes no such thing happens, and the series developed converges since the remainder term vanishes at infinity. This is a standard procedure.

Comment: @Allawonder Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be defined as $f(x) = e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$. Then $f$ is a smooth map with $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$. Now if you develop the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$, you will find that this series also converges everywhere since all the Taylor coefficeints are zero. Of course, this does mean that $f$ is analytic, for if it were then it would be the zero function, which it is not. May be I am missing something.

Comment: Would it suffice to observe $\gamma$ and $l(x)=\int_0^x |\gamma'(t)|dt$ are analytic? I think your definition of sine is using inverse function of $l$, $\gamma$ and projection. Probably the inverse function theorem for analytic functions will also need to be used.

Comment: @Insubordinate That seems promising to me. Thanks.

Comment: @caffeinemachine Your example (again also well-known) doesn't satisfy all the conditions of Taylor's theorem, which I was referring to. I wasn't merely claiming that a function's Taylor series always converges to the function, absolutely. From Taylor's theorem, if derivatives up to order $n-1$ are continuous in a closed interval and the $n$th derivative exists in the corresponding open interval, then the function can be expanded in a polynomial at some point in the interval, with a certain remainder term $R_n.$ If $R_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty,$ then clearly the series obtained $=f(x).$

Comment: @Allawonder Thanks. I would like to read the theorem and the proof that you are referring to. Would be able to give a reference or add the proof as an answer if it is not too long. Thank you.

Comment: @caffeinemachine There is one on page 109 of Baby Rudin, I think.

Comment: @Allawonder You are right. the error term involves derivative at $0$, and hene one can control the error term by Sterling. Thanks.